# Uniform convergence and continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ be a power series. Let $R$ be the radius of convergence. I have proved that for $[-r,r] \subset (-R,R)$ the power series is uniformly convergent. There is a conclusion that states that it means also the power series is continuous. I don't see how.

I know there is a theorem which states if each $a_nx^n$ is continuous, and the power series is uniformly convergent then it is also continuous. However, how do I know each $a_nx^n$ is continuous? $x^n/n$ for example is not at x = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Use the fact the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous. Your power series is the limit of the sequence $f_N(x) := \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n x^n$. Each term $f_N$ is continuous, being a finite sum of continuous functions.

Comment: How do we know $a_nx^n$ is continuous

Comment: It's a finite product of continuous functions $u_1(x) = a_n$ and $u_2(x) = x$.

Comment: what about a_n = 1/n?

Comment: As a function of $x$, it is constant, so in particular, it's continuous.